# Are there any guidelines for creating your own boons in Open Legend?

Tags: open-legend

I have recently started playing [Open Legend](http://www.openlegendrpg.com) and the number of boons and feats seem a bit limited especially after playing games like D&D 3.5.

Are there any official guidelines to create new boons?

If possible i want to create a boon that gives aspects to the area like in FATE.

If there aren't any I am willing to settle for homebrew systems for creating new boons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really aren't any guidelines for creating new boons (or banes) within the rules, although the list is meant to be expandable in individual settings. That said, many of them can be used creatively, since the mechanics are the important part.

If you believe that there is a (yet unmade) bane, boon, or feat that would work well in your game, you may want to post on [the Open Legend community site.](https://community.openlegendrpg.com/) There is an entire section devoted to house rules, and people will be happy to help you develop the idea in the context of Open Legend.